# Is time order disrupted in these sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction

Recently I came upon these sentences in one of my exercises, and I was wondering whether time "continuity" or chronology was disrupted here.

Task: "There are mistakes in eight of these sentences. Correct the sentences where necessary.
Write 'Ok' if the sentences is already correct".

1. > We can't remember where did we leave our car.

- **My version:** We can't remember where we have left our car.
- **Author's version:** We can't remember where we left our car.

2. > Now I know why didn't you tell me what you were buying!

- **My version:** Now I know why you haven't told me what you were buying!
- **Author's version:** Now I know why you didn't tell me what you were buying!

Imprimis, I am not a native speaker, however, I have been told that you can't mix up certain tenses, for instance, Present Simple + Past Simple etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is very tricky.  The author's versions are indeed correct.  I'm not sure how you can learn this other than to spend a lot of time speaking with native speakers, or people who have spent time in English-speaking countries. Your versions are certainly understandable, but awkward.